# Проблема загрузки модели PyTorch в приложение с виртуальной машины

Tags: python, python-3.x, pytorch, виртуальная-машина, segmentation-fault

У меня возникла проблема с загрузкой модели PyTorch в приложение, которое я разрабатываю на виртуальной машине. Я создал экземпляр модели, используя тот же путь к файлу, который корректно работает в автономном сценарии, но когда я пытаюсь загрузить его из приложения, я получаю ошибку сегментации.

Вот код из файла `test.py` на виртуальной машине:

```
model = UC_Model(pModel_filepath="/mnt/confiance/common/UC_Data_Folder/UC_La_Organisacion_Anomaly_Detection/models/trained_perceiver/best_model_spectra")
print("model: ", model)
```

Модель загружается нормально:

```
model:  <UCLaOrganisacionAnomalyDetection.UC_Model object at 0x7f687d869a00>
```

Но когда я делаю это из разрабатываемого приложения, возникает следующая проблема:

```
   .create Model from '/mnt/confiance/common/UC_Data_Folder/UC_La_Organisacion_Anomaly_Detection/models/trained_perceiver/best_model_spectra'
./kaa.sh: line 48: 1870463 Segmentation fault      (core dumped) python3 kaa.py $1
```

Así que estoy en la misma máquina virtual.

Вот код приложения, которое я создал для загрузки модели из файла :

```
#-------------------------------------------------------------------------------
## Launch the inference computation
# @param pDictParams : parameter dictionary
# @return parameter dictionary updated
def launchInference(pDictParams):
    TUI.TUIprint("Action: Inference","Action")

    # create the model instance
    if has_method(pDictParams['pluginUCXAI'],'UCXAI_createModel'):
        print("pDictParams['pluginUCXAI']: ", pDictParams['pluginUCXAI'])
        aiModel=pDictParams['pluginUCXAI'].UCXAI_createModel(pDictParams)
```

В `pDictParams['pluginUCXAI']` у нас есть экземпляр класса `UCLaOrganisationAnomalyDetection_Xplique`:

```
import UCLaOrganisacionAnomalyDetection

##------------------------------------------------------------------------------
## Class for Use case vs Library
class UCLaOrganisacionAnomalyDetection_Xplique(kaasrc.plugin_collection.Plugin):
    #---------------------------------------------------------------------------------
    ## Class constructor
    # @param self : l'instance de la classe
    def __init__(self):
        super().__init__()
        self.nom = "UCLaOrganisacionAnomalyDetection"
        self.description = "Detect bad vibrations in time series"
        self.modeles = ["PerceiverLogit"]
        self.bibliotheque = "Xplique"
        self.methodes = ["Hsic","Occlusion","KernelShap","Rise","Lime","Sobol"]
        self.metriques = None
        self.UC=UCLaOrganisacionAnomalyDetection

    #---------------------------------------------------------------------------
    ## Create an instance of the model
    # @param pDictParams : parameter dictionary
    # @return the instance of the model
    # @remark Call directly UC_createModel() of UC model
    def UCXAI_createModel(self,pDictParams):
        return self.UC.UC_createModel(pDictParams)
```

А UC.UC_createModel(pDictParams) - это:

```
#-------------------------------------------------------------------------------
## Create an instance of the model
# @param pDictParams : parameter dictionary
# @return the instance of the model
def UC_createModel(pDictParams):
    # shortcuts
    pModelBase=pDictParams['modelBase']
    pModelpath=pDictParams['modelpath']
    pModelfile=pDictParams['modelfile']
    pCode=pDictParams['code']

    # get model file
    ficModel=os.path.join(pModelBase,pModelpath,pModelfile)
    print("   .create Model from '%s'"%ficModel,flush=True)

    # create model instance from 'model' parameter
    aiModel=UC_Model(ficModel)
    print("      ",aiModel.name,"-/-",pCode,flush=True)
```

И я думаю, что дамп ядра приходит с `aiModel=UC_Model(ficModel)`.

Я думаю, что это должно быть проблемой видеокарты. Я всегда ставлю CUDA=0 в приложении

Comment: Версия питона та же, например? И версия `pythorch`. Да, и что за метод `UC_Model`, это ваш или из `pytorch` или что это?

Comment: Спасибо за ваш комментарий @CrazyElf . Класс UC_Model - это пользовательский класс, специфичный для вашего приложения или фреймворка. Он используется для создания экземпляров определенных моделей для обработки данных из различных сценариев использования. Этот класс реализует специфическую для домена функциональность, такую как загрузка модели, выполнение выводов и т. д. Я собираюсь проверить, что скрипт и класс используют одну и ту же версию python

Comment: Это одинаковые версии python: 3.8.10 и pytorch: 1.9.0+cu102. @CrazyElf Эта ошибка сегментации неисправностей - настоящая загадка

Comment: Я использую Perceiver. Может быть, именно поэтому загрузка модели в приложение немного затруднена: она создает ошибку Segmentation Fault @CrazyElf  ? Я знаю, что архитектура Perceiver немного необычна, и, возможно, мое приложение не поддерживает их, хотя они не создают никаких проблем при работе со скриптом.

Comment: Не знаю, что ещё вам подсказать. У меня больше мыслей нет )